# Sharepoint hit counter is not displayed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, hitcounter

I followed the instructions here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825532

After that when I preview my page, I can't see the hitcounter. I learned that it may be related to permissions of the site but I couldn't find how to do it.

Is it realy related to permissions ? If so what should I do to ? And any external solution  (except this one: http://hitcounter.codeplex.com/) would help, the one in pharanthesis, I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nspsharing.blogspot.com/2009/11/hit-counter-sharepoint-designer-is-not.html